# How can I disable copy and paste for Android in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

For iOS, we used `contextMenuHidden: true` and it worked.

For Android, the above doesn't work so we've tried:

1. `selectTextOnFocus: false`
2. Wrapping the TextInput in a View with `removeClippedSubviews: true`
3. Replicating this commit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/32635/files
4. Doing `Clipboard.setString('')` in onBlur, onFocus and onSelectionChange of the TextInput

No luck - any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: yup there are more than one answers we got on StackOverflow, but in actuality, nothing is working fine for android.